# Kendo UI: Dynamic field generation (data-binding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have trying to make dynamic form field generation from external JSON "field schema" using pure Kendo UI. 
So what's recommended way to bind dataSource of object (which i currently editing) to my new generated fields? (fields may have different types of kendo UI widgets)

(i have tried to stick field source with the item source but it seems like not good solution)

Here's my jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/yayabapono/15/edit?html,js,output

P.S Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you just generate the proper javascript server-side? I don't see what you are using in your tags? ASP, MVC, PHP, something like that?

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using API provided by Laravel as backend (PHP).
Maybe i'm wrong but it's no matter what service i've used as backend, right? I just need to know what is the recommended way to bind inputs which was genereated by json from another datasource instance to my source of current user (userSource.at(0) in my jsbin for example ).
In my jsbin i have no bindings to the model, but i want to bind input fields with the data of user
(again sorry for the mistakes and my english and thanks for your time)

Comment: It matters to me because if you were using any of the C#-based languages, I could pull samples for you from our production code. The method I'm recommending is to *not bind schema info on the client* but to use your server-side engine to render all the javascript. You could still deliver the data by Ajax/JSON if you wanted, but I think you need to render the schema correctly first, on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for advice Jasmine. But even if i do render javascript on the server-side i still do not understand concepts of bindings if  i need to dynamically generate my fields from meta-desription of it